# Mat table not refreshed after update

Tags: angular7, mat-table

I have two table where the datasource gets updated once we update the record in first table and push to second table which is the updated record called from service, simply both the tables will have two service calls; the service returns the response correctly but the table is not getting updated in frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You need to use OnPush strategy in your component
2-  if 1 not work so You can use change detector from ChangeDetectorRef in your component
3- if 1 and 2 not work you should know to practice pipe async with behavior Subject and observables